# textfield hiding using css based on tag directive

Tags: html, css

I have a custom tag within my html, the custom tag is a directive, within the custom I have a text field.

How can I hide that text field using css based on that tag

**html**

```
<state>
<input type="text"/>
</state>
```

Comment: Do you want to toggle the visibility based on condition?

Comment: You can try the following **[Toggle Visibility Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/quwvb65g/3/)**. Its a very basic case.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
body state input{
    display: none;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/me7Lhjwx/)**